# Как правильно передавать ref (useRef) в React другим компонентам? Допустимо ли объявление ref в файле контекста?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Вопрос в принципе касается только теории useRef(), без кода.

Нужно объявлять ref в родительском компоненте и передавать через props в дочерние? А что, если прокидывать нужно много раз, или нужно получить доступ к ref компонента из другого на том же уровне вложенности (child to child)?

И можно ли объявлять ref в файле контекста (createContext), получая доступ где нужно и присваивать элементу DOM, затем использовать его где и как требуется?
Я делал так и это работало, я даже мог использовать ref для написания методов в файле контекста. Но возникает вопрос о безопасности данных, так как если поставить один ref к нескольким разным DOM-элементам, это точно вызовет непредвиденные изменения.